# Diagram of Patent wo2000006442a1

Tags: diagrams, wo2000006442a1

> I am researching patents regarding rainwash depression. Do you have any diagrams of patent Patent wo2000006442a1 ?

Answer (score 1):

[WO 2000006442 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/wo2000006442a1) "Apparatus for Reducing Road Vehicle Spray"
is a **[patent family member](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent_family)** of [US 20020109347 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20020109347).

### This can be seen in the "Also Published as" section on Google Patents.

[image]

The figures in [US 20020109347 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20020109347) can be seen on Google Patents and some of the diagrams are posted below.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]